# create_function has been deprecated - is my updated code correct?

Tags: php, wordpress, deprecated

The create_function has been deprecated in PHP 7.2. I don't know my way around PHP too well, but I think what I've done below is correct. Would you mind checking, and let me know if I missed anything?

Thank you in advance!

**Here is the old code:**

```
usort($users, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcasecmp($a->first_name, $b->first_name);'));
```

**Here is my new code:**

```
function($a, $b) use ($users) {
  return "return strnatcasecmp($a->first_name, $b->first_name);"; 
}
```

Thank you again.

Comment: Tried testing your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($users, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcasecmp($a->first_name, $b->first_name);'));
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
usort($users, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a->first_name, $b->first_name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove commas in return, try this:

```
function($a, $b) use ($users) {
  return strnatcasecmp($a->first_name, $b->first_name); 
}
```